Add attachment to an email in Outlook when the new email button is clicked
I need the below script to run when I create a new email in Outlook. Currently it runs when I send an email.
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "you have created a new message please ensure the attachment has attached"
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
     
    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
    myAttachments.Add "C:\attachment.docx", _
      olByValue, 1, "Test"
    myItem.Display
End Sub

I amended my code. Now Outlook opens two emails when I click on new email. One email has the attachment and the message box is displayed but a blank email is also created.
Private WithEvents objinspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objinspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
        MsgBox "newinspector"
    
        Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
        myAttachments.Add "C:\attachment.docx", _
          olByValue, 1, "Test"
        myItem.Display
    End If
End Sub


Does this answer your question? outlook event newMail (newItem)

To reference the item created on clicking the New Email button:
Set myItem = Inspector.currentItem

Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objinspectors As Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objinspectors = Inspectors
End Sub


Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)

Dim myItem As MailItem
Dim myAttachments As Attachments

If TypeName(Inspector.currentItem) = "MailItem" Then

    Debug.Print "newinspector"
    'MsgBox "newinspector"
    
    Set myItem = Inspector.currentItem
    Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
    
    myAttachments.Add "C:\attachment.docx", olByValue, 1, "Test"
    
End If

End Sub

